# Loading haarcascade classifier in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am trying to load haarcascade classifier from a downloaded xml file with opencv in Python.

```py
import cv2
import os

haar_model_local = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
print(haar_model_local)
print(os.path.exists(haar_model_local))
print(os.path.isfile(haar_model_local))

cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_model_local)
```

I am getting this error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) D:\bld\libopencv_1675730129252\work\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp:692: error: (-5:Bad argument) Input file is invalid in function 'cv::FileStorage::Impl::open'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\SoftwareDev\Python_Projekte\gesichtserkennungstest\Gesichtserkennung_Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_model_local)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemError: <class 'cv2.CascadeClassifier'> returned a result with an exception set
```

What is wrong here or what I am missing?

I am trying to run this on Windows 10, with Anaconda:

```json
conda list -f opencv --json
[
  {
    "base_url": "https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge",
    "build_number": 1,
    "build_string": "py311h1ea47a8_1",
    "channel": "conda-forge",
    "dist_name": "opencv-4.7.0-py311h1ea47a8_1",
    "name": "opencv",
    "platform": "win-64",
    "version": "4.7.0"
  }
]
```

Comment: please show a hexdump of that XML file. you probably didn't save the actual file itself, but the Github HTML page that _presents_ the content of the file

Comment: You are right. I somehow managed to download the "wrong" file from here:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

Comment: I knew to ask for this because you aren't the first in that situation ;)